# How to find the old Google search result for a site that doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: search-engine

Recently, a forum went into maintainance mode so it's not readable. However, the search results display a lot of topics that I would like to see. So if those search results memorized the forum's text, how can I get to see that text in the form in which it was found?

I've heard that there was a "Read from Cache" button (or something like that), but now it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to see if the page you want to see is in the **Google cached pages**.

In order to do that, you perform your search on Google in the usual way and, when you get a list of results, you'll see that for each result, next to the web address text, there's a small arrow: if you click on that, it opens a small menu which contains **Cached**, a [cashed link](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en).

What's a cached link?

> Cached links show you what a webpage looked like the last time Google
>   visited it.
>
> Google takes a snapshot of each webpage as a backup in case the
>   current page isn't available. These pages then become part of Google’s
>   cache. If you click on a link that says “Cached,” you’ll see the
>   version of the site that Google stored.

[image: Cached link example]

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out right after asking the question. I just didn't know that the option was under the arrow.